# How do i make my method more Object Oriented?

Tags: java, oop

This Code you see below is a method in my Bomberman School Project. We got some Tutorial Videos to get us started and the Teacher in the Video mentioned that we should make this Code more Object Oriented. Nothing is coming to my mind as to how i could make this more Object Oriented.

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        // TODO: Make this more Object Oriented
        if (message instanceof PlayerJoined) {
            PlayerJoinedControl control = ControlFactory.instance().createPlayerJoinedControl();
            control.playerJoined((PlayerJoined)message);
        } else if (message instanceof ErrorMessage) {
            // TODO: Create ErrorMessageControl, make it show message in console of game
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + ((ErrorMessage) message).getErrorMessage());
        } else if (message instanceof StartGame) {
            // TODO: ADD METHOD IMPLEMENTATION
        }
    }
```

My Question to the Community is how I could make this more Object Oriented. I am open for suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about improving working code, *may* be suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: You are not really looking to make it more objected oriented, but you are looking for the correct **pattern** to use.

Comment: In that small scale it does not really matter and the method is okay-ish. But if it grows, you _could_ add a `Map<Class<? extends Message>, Consumer<? extends Message>>` or similar, which holds the message type and the action to do for it. Then you can simply do `map.get(message.getClass()).accept(message)` and thats it. And if you want to have compile-time safety for the generic-type-setup, create a dedicated class wrapping the type and the consumer in one object and have a `Set` on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ploymorphism and implement handleMessage in each subclass. Example:

```
PlayerJoinedHandler extends MessageHandler {

public void handleMessage(PlayerJoined message) {
      PlayerJoinedControl control = ControlFactory.instance().createPlayerJoinedControl();
            control.playerJoined((PlayerJoined)message);

}

}

ErrorMessageHandler extends MessageHandler {

   public void handleMessage(ErrorMessage message) {
       System.out.println("ERROR: " + ((ErrorMessage) message).getErrorMessage());
   }

}
```

With Java 8 you can actualy use lambda for these classes and just have an interface:

```
interface MessageHandler<T extends Message> {

      public void handleMessage(T message);

    }

    (t)->{
       PlayerJoinedControl control = ControlFactory.instance().createPlayerJoinedControl();
                control.playerJoined((PlayerJoined)message);
    }
```